# Moving an <svg><image> into a blob picture

Tags: javascript, image, svg, aspect-ratio

This question is for senior web developers with extended knowledge in SVG.
I'm working on a project where I need to move an SVG IMAGE
into a BITARRAY link and into an IMG SRC.

So far I have succeeded doing this with regular svg shapes (rect,path...), but when im
 
trying to do the same with an IMAGE tag the picture collapses to an empty image.
i have used the MDN method of this proceedure, you can see the method in this link [Drawing DOM objects into a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)

Somethings to note:
 * I have succeded loading the image itself into the svg image element
 * The image markup

```
<svg version="1.1" width="19" height="19" preserveaspectratio="none">
<image x="0" y="0" width="18.867924528301888" height="18.867924528301888" id="box_2_rect" fill="#000" href="http://someUrl/a809e372db0b6d2dfaa09b3039205ab6.jpg"/>
</svg>
```

I'm breaking my head on this but information on the web is very scarce.
just someone please explain why the IMAGE tag brakes everything !!!!

Comment: The `href` attribute in an SVG `<image>` tag belongs to the xlink namespace and not the SVG one. You should correct that first.

Comment: i did what you wrote now the image dosn't brake it shows all shapes BUT the image element wont show

Comment: Quoting your tutorial link: "SVG images aren't allowed to load any external resources, for example, even ones that appear to be from the same domain. Resources such as raster images (such as JPEG images) or <iframe>s have to be inlined as data: URIs." So you have to convert your image to a dataurl, before you can insert it into the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating this thread with the answer i found.
Basically when using a foreign object tag all its content must be origin free, meaning no reffence to files on your or others server. the content of the foreign object must be clean of origins. this means you cant show an image, inside a foreign object tag. I am not sure about the contents of the svg tag. however canvas can do this and if your trying to copy html to canvas you can do that with the technique described in the link i shared, and than when your canvas is ready with the html, tou can load the images into it placing them on the canvas in thr right places. this is some programming youll need to do.